# Supporting Multiple Input Devices

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, input, keyboard, gamepad

I'm currently developing a PC game with the assistance of XNA and I'm integrating keyboard and gamepad control support. Up until now I've only supported gamepad control, and finding an elegant way to allow the player to choose one or the other is posing a complicated task to resolve.

I was thinking of creating a class that would sort of convert either input into a universal sort of data that the game could then use for the player's character and the rest of the game to interpret.

Then, I thought maybe it would be simpler to create a duplicate of my main character's class, except to accept keyboard input instead of the gamepad input.

Can anybody offer any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was thinking of creating a class that would sort of convert either input into a universal sort of data that the game could then use for the player's character and the rest of the game to interpret.

This is the right idea. Use a abstract action codes instead of actual Key Codes or Button Codes. Not only does this let you support keyboard + gamepad, it also lets you (or the player) remap controls.